# Permission granted to a programatically created role is not working!

Tags: users, 9

In a custom module form, I am using this code for the submission handler.

```php
$role = Role::create(['id' => 'member', 'label' => t('Member')]);
$role->grantPermission('Renew membership');
$role->save();
```

It seems to work, since the output of `ksm($role)` shows the permission between the permissions given to the role.

```
$role Drupal\user\Entity\Role (23)
  Properties (23)
    protected id -> string (6) "member"
    protected label -> UTF-8 string (8) "Adhérent"
    protected weight -> integer 1
    protected permissions -> array (1)
      0 => string (16) "Renew membership"
```

When I look at */admin/people/permissions*, I notice the role is correctly listed (which means it has been created), the permission too, but the permission isn't granted to the role.

> [image: screenshot]

What is wrong in the code I use?

Comment: "Renew membership" is almost definitely the permission's label. You'll need to pass the permission's id to `grantPermission()`. You can get the id by reviewing the module that provides it (simplest case is that it's in the *MODULE.permissions.yml* file). You may also be able to guess it by inspecting the permission form.

Comment: Alternatively, you can grant the permission in the UI and then export configuration to see what the permission's id is.

Comment: You need to pass the id. Also, verify permissions by checking the database or doing a config dump for that role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Role::grantPermission()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21Role.php/function/Role%3A%3AgrantPermission/9.3.x) doesn't check the permission is correct or it's defined by any module; it just adds the permission, if the role doesn't already have that permission.

```php
public function grantPermission($permission) {
  if ($this->isAdmin()) {
    return $this;
  }
  if (!$this->hasPermission($permission)) {
    $this->permissions[] = $permission;
  }
  return $this;
}
```

This also means that, if the code uses the permission title, which is what /admin/people/permissions shows, it doesn't use the correct ID for that permission. The code that handles permissions is also case sensitive; this means it considers *Renew membership*, *Renew Membership*, and *renew membership* three different permissions.

Since /admin/people/permissions shows *Renew Membership* as permission, that is a known permission. You just need to use its ID, which in most of the cases is the permission title in lower-case characters.

```php
$role = Role::create(['id' => 'member', 'label' => t('Member')]);
$role->grantPermission('renew membership');
$role->save();
```

If that isn't a permission defined from a module you wrote, and you don't know which module defines that permission, and where, you can look up at the markup used in the /admin/people/permissions page, where you will probably find the permission ID.
For example, for the per *Administer contact forms and contact form settings* permission, the value of the *data-drupal-selector* attribute used for its `<tr>` is *edit-permissions-administer-contact-forms*.

```html
<tr data-drupal-selector="edit-permissions-administer-contact-forms" class="odd">
  <td><div class="permission"><span class="title">Administer contact forms and contact form settings</span></div></td>
  <!-- omitted markup -->
</tr>
```

Removing *edit-permissions-* and replacing the hyphens with spaces, it becomes *administer contact forms*, which is the permission ID, listed in the [contact.permissions.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21contact%21contact.permissions.yml/9.3.x) file.

```yaml
administer contact forms:
  title: 'Administer contact forms and contact form settings'
access site-wide contact form:
  title: 'Use the site-wide contact form'
access user contact forms:
  title: 'Use users'' personal contact forms'
```